# How to shuffle a number so that it can be maximum multiple of the number 30 ?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, big-numbers

If i have a large number (<=10^5 Digits) how can i tell that if i can shuffle the number so that it become a multiple of 30 . if it is possible then i have to find the maximum multiple . Suppose if i have this number 
  97980 
if i make any combination of this number , all the combinations will be divisible by 30 , but the maximum one is 99870 . How can i shuffle this very large number and know whether it is possible or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately (or unfortunately) shuffling digits does not affect whether a number is divisible by 3.

Casting-out-nines will quickly tell you whether a number is divisible by three.  If so, then you need some digit to be zero and to transfer this to the units place, in order to have a result that is divisible by $30$.

Otherwise it is not possible to achieve this divisibility by $30$.

To maximize the multiple of $30$, just sort the digits in descending order from left to right (all big digits in high-order positions).

Comment: Initially, I also used the term "descending". But for such a simple question, I presume that it might be easier for the OP to understand if you make it as explicit as possible (e.g., "from largest to smallest").

Comment: @barakmanos: Well, the nym CodeHead and manipulation of more than one hundred thousand digits suggests at least some programming experience.

Answer (score 1):

The number can be rearranged as a multiple of $30$ if and only if:

- It contains the digit $0$
- The sum of its digits is divisible by $3$

---

In order to obtain the maximum multiple of $30$:

- Rearrange the digits from largest to smallest
- Divide the result by $30$